# JPQL TIMEDIFF equvalent

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, object-persistence

Is there an equvalent of the SQL TIMEDIFF functionality in JPQL? Is that possible to query with JPQL to find the records in specific time range?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an equvalent of SQL TEMEDIFF functionality in JPQL?

Is this standard SQL? Any link?

> Is that possible to query with JPQL to find the records in specific time range?

Did you try to use [`BETWEEN`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_between) (or the semantic equivalent):

```
datetime_expression [NOT] BETWEEN datetime_expression AND datetime_expression
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p 
from Person p  
where p.modifyTime > '2010-03-04 23:59:59'  
  and p.modifyTime < '2010-03-24 00:00:00'
```